# UNION com 2 DATABASES, SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou precisando integrar 2 `TABLES` provenientes de `DB`diferentes em um mesmo `DGV`.

Encontrei vários tutoriais, mas nenhum que me ajudasse desde a configuração para a conexão, pelo menos não da forma em que eu trabalho com as conexões.

Segue um ex. de como eu chamo um Select:

```
MySqlConnection conexaoSLT = ClassConexao.DBEMG();

MySqlCommand _comando = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM tabel1 WHERE Carro = @tipoCarro"), conexaoSLT );

MySqlDataReader _reader = _comando.ExecuteReader();
_reader.Read();

....
```

Como eu consigo conectar dois *databases* em um `SELECT` `UNION` ?

Comment: É só colocar o nome da database antes do nome da tabela. Supondo que a database se chama A, então é só usar A.table1. O restante do select é normal. É sql server?

Comment: @MaurícioSanches: O que é DGV?

Comment: @JoséDiz DataGridView

Comment: @MaurícioSanches: Ok.

Answer (score 1):

1. Deve verificar se o usuário que está utilizando na sua conexão possui permissão para leitura no outro banco de dados.
2. No `SELECT` deve utilizar o nome do outro banco antes da referência da tabela.

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT C.NOMCLI, C.CODCLI, E.CODCLI FROM DB1.CLIENTES C, DB2.CLIENTES E
```

Pode acontecer que em seus bancos de dados seja necessário colocar o usuário antes do nome do banco por exemplo:

```
SELECT C.NOMCLI, C.CODCLI, E.CODCLI FROM USUARIO1.DB1.CLIENTES C, USUARIO 2.DB2.CLIENTES E
```

O Resto para fazer o `UNION`, `WHERE` E ETC, você só referencia normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Desde que o usuário tenha permissão nos dois bancos.

Assumindo que seja SQL-Server e que as tabelas sejam iguais nos dois bancos:

```
SELECT * FROM OUTRO_BANCO..TABELA WHERE ..... 
UNION
SELECT * FROM ESSE_BANCO..TABELA WHERE .....
```

Se as tabelas forem diferentes:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM OUTRO_BANCO..TABELA WHERE ..... 
UNION
SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM ESSE_BANCO..TABELA WHERE .....
```

Se for Oracle e tabelas iguais:

```
SELECT * FROM OUTRO_BANCO.TABELA WHERE ..... 
UNION
SELECT * FROM ESSE_BANCO.TABELA WHERE .....
```

Oracle e tabelas diferentes:

```
 SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM OUTRO_BANCO.TABELA WHERE ..... 
 UNION
 SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM ESSE_BANCO.TABELA WHERE .....
```

Comment: Perfeito! Estou em SQL-Server sim, porém continua dando erro. Provavelmente porque o usuario não tem permissão para o acesso ao outro banco. Estão hospedados na mesma conta, mas são users e senhas diferentes, se tiver alguma dica de como eu configuro essa permissão, certamente resolveria meu problema.

Comment: USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GRANT SELECT ON sys.sql_logins TO Sylvester1;  
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE to Sylvester1;  
GO